# Suggesting a good reference, & solving a linear diophantine equation in two variables with $\gcd =1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, reference-request

Request a suitable reference for Diophantine equation starting with linear, with geometric 
intuition

Please recommend some good source that starts from linear diophantine equations 
in two unknowns, and deals with their geometric sense; then goes to higher order 
equations in a similar manner. I am feeling there is no proper source / book 
published on the subject, that is made in such a manner.
I want to progress, with geometric intuition developed, to higher order equation.

I feel that the only book/source that does not deal with abstract algebra for 
that treatment, is of Bashmakova; but it seems too terse and starts with "genus" right from the start. Any more grounds-up book /source is requested, that does not need abstract algebra to explain.

---

Let the Diophantine equation be $3x + 4y =7$. The $\gcd=1$ for $a=3, b=4$. Obviously $\gcd \mid 7$. If solve in reverse using EEA to find the Bezout's coefficients, then: $x = -1, y =1$ is the particular solution by the below steps.

$$
\begin{align}
4 = 3.1 + 1 <--> & \ 1 = 4.1 + 3.(-1) \\
3= 1.3 + 0 <--> & \  \\
\end{align}
$$

For $c=7$, the Bezout's coefficients are : $x=-7, y =7$.

Hopefully, need find out the parametric form for finding out the infinite solutions. This form is given by the pair of values: ($-7+4t, 7-3t$) or ($-7-4t, 7+3t$).

Checking if it is correct, let $t=1$: the pair ($-7+4 =-3, 7-3 =4$) or ($-7-4 =-11, 7+3=10$). Substituting in the given equation, get:

$$
\begin{align}
3.(-3) + 4.(4) <--> & \ 3.(-11) + 4.(10) \\
-9+16 <--> & \ -33 + 40 \\
7 <--> & \ 7 \\
\end{align}
$$

---

The issue is that the book states the solution as having the parametric form as $(x= 1+4t, y = 1-3t)$. This should be $(x= -7+4t, y = 7-3t)$, as per me; but is yielding the correct $c$ (y-intercept) value of $7$ still.

Comment: Yes, you have done well. What is the question?

Comment: note that $1+4t=-7+4(t+2)$ and $1-3t=7-3(t+2)$.

Comment: @awllower I don't know why the books in general love to eat such steps? Thanks a lot for that.

Comment: @all Please recommend some good source that starts from linear diophantine equations in two unknowns, and deals with their geometric sense; then goes to higher order equations in a similar manner. I am feeling there is no proper source / book published on the subject, that is made in such a manner.

Comment: What is exactly your doubt?

Comment: @gimusi I want to progress, with geometric intuition developed, to higher order equation. I feel that the only book/source that does not deal with abstract algebra for that treatment, is of Bashmakova; but it seems too terse.

Comment: Why you argue that: “The issue is that the book states the solution as having the parametric form as $(x= 1+4t, y = 1-3t)$. This should be $(x= -7+4t, y = 7-3t)$...”.Aren’t them equivalent? Sorry but I don’t get your point.

Comment: @gimusi Sorry, I thought about other issue. Yes, they are, but "now" and was not clear to me earlier. Seems simple, but beginning is like that hopefully.

Comment: @jiten Don't worry for that, we are here to discuss every issue. Sometimes the difficult part is uderstand what the issue is. In this case I imagine that it is clear to you that: 3x + 4y =3(x-4t) + 4(y+3t) =7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the "reference" half of your question, I would recommend John Stillwell's "Elements of Number Theory". He includes a great deal of historical motivation and context, while taking the reader from basics, through linear Diophantine equations, the "Pell" Equation, quadratic reciprocity, the Four Square theorem and he even motivates rings/ideals. The pre-requisites are minimal.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between your book's solution and your solution is that you've used the EEA to find that $4-3 = 1$, then multiplied that by $7$ to get $7\cdot 4 -7\cdot 3 = 7$, and used that as your starting point for parametrizing the space of solutions, while your book's solution (most likely) noted the rather obvious fact that $4+3 = 7$, and used that as the starting point for the parametrisation.

Their approach is fast and dependent on luck (it wouldn't really be a shortcut at all had we wanted $4x+3y = 5$, for instance), while your approach is a bit slower, but always works (to you, the number $7$ could've been anything, and finding the solution would take the same amount of time regardless). The space of solutions is the same, and both methods are correct.

Comment: Please elaborate how $4+3=7$ is used to have a shortcut. Has the use made of some identity, like $\ gcd (a,b) = \gcd(a+b,b)$. I am stating a randomly chosen identity, for explaining myself.

Comment: @jiten It is a shortcut because you don't need to use the EEA to find Bezout's coefficients, and then multiply up. You just find the coefficients you need immediately. I could've written $1\cdot 4 + 1\cdot 3 = 7$ to make it clearer. But you can clearly see that choosing $t = 0$ in the book's parametrisation gives these coefficients, so I think it's a fairly reasonable assumption that this is their starting point.

Comment: But this shortcut would not then apply at all for $c=5$ case.

Comment: @jiten That's right. As I said in my post, it is fast, but depends on luck.

Comment: I was confused by the words "so well" in your response, so needed your confirmation.

Comment: @jiten Oh, I'll fix that then.